# how does $ sign in "jQuery(function($){...}" refer to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dollar-sign

below, it says $ sign refers to jQuery. i need help understand how?

```
jQuery(function($){
    // Here `$` refers to jQuery
});
```

Comment: Just look at the very bottom of the source http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js

Comment: What do you mean? How it is done behind the scenes or how you can use it?

Comment: Because jQuery will give the jQuery as parameter to the provided function, and the parameter is called $ and thus refers to jQuery.

Comment: downvotes seem rather harsh to me - I didn't know myself until trying to find the answer that jQuery passes itself as the first argument to a `document.ready` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a function to jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    ...
});
```

It's the same as using jQuery's "document ready" handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

however the *argument* passed to that function is actually the global jQuery object itself - it's just that most such handlers never use that parameter.  Hence the *real* signature is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    ...
});
```

so, within that function `$` is a local alias to the global jQuery object.  The variable name *could* be anything you wanted, but `$` is a popular alias for `jQuery`, and the default global alias unless you call `jQuery.noConflict()`.

This is described in more detail in the paragraph "*Aliasing the jQuery Namespace*" at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: alnitak, we can use `jQuery(document).ready(function(anyname){...});` , right? here anyname=jquery,then.

Comment: @burhan yes, that's correct, per my second-last paragraph, but _only within that function_.

Comment: that is, it passes the jquery object to the function as its argument. not "`this`"

Comment: how can we change the value of $ in another function?

Comment: by either nesting those functions inside this one, or maybe with `jQuery.noConflict()`.  It rather depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

That function is a so called allonymous function where jQuery runs that allonymous function with the first parameter this.

So just for understanding it makes something like this:

```
function jQuery(xx) {
    xx(this);
}
```

Comment: This snippet would show the behaviour, but is way too simplified to be of any meaning I'm afraid.

Comment: Well your both are right I just wanted to point why $ is a jQuery object. If I guess right then burhan doesn't know the concept of allonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example for show you how is it possibile

```
function externalLibrary(b) {
    if(typeof b === 'function') {
        b(externalLibrary);
    }else {
        // other stuff
    }

}

var myFunc = function(aliasOfExternalLibrary) {
    // here aliasOfExternalLibrary is a reference to externalLibrary
}
externalLibrary( myFunc );
```

jQuery [do the same](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L160) (in one more complex system)